# Why can I not run an application installed using sudo without sudo?

Tags: software-installation, sudo

I noticed that after installing something using `sudo` I cannot run the application without `sudo` even though the executable is in my path.  I have to go into the application directory and manually change the permissions (using [`chmod -R o=g <application>/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3729108/3585557)).  I have experienced this in 16.04, 14.04, and maybe even in 12.04.  Why is this the default behavior and how can I change this?

As an example, I just compiled and installed [KeePassX 0.4.4](https://www.keepassx.org/downloads/0-4).  Using the default installation commands (`qmake`, `make`, `sudo make install`), the executable is `/usr/bin/keepassx` with the expected permissions, `755`, but files this executable points to, in `/usr/share/keepassx/` have permissions `750` preventing execution without using `sudo`.

When I install an application using `apt`, `apt-get`, or `dpkg -i` I use `sudo` but all users can run the application.  How do I mimic this behavior when compiling and installing an application from source?  I realize I could add a `chmod` command to the `Makefile` but is there a way to make a change once that will propagate to future installs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of programs that will sill be in your path that won't work for normal users.  An example is `adduser`.  So it would depend on the program that you want to run.

I don't know what the `KeePassX 0.4.4` program does, but it would be up to the developers of whether to make the program available to normal users or to require the elevated command to run.

As far as compiling, which it appears that you did that correctly, you should build and compile the programs as a normal user.  Only run the `make install` part with the elevated command.  This way the program becomes install system-wide.

You shouldn't have go into the system to make any changes.  If you change the files you might actually break the application.

Some programs needs to be run as root so that they will have access to certain files that normal users can't access, such as using the command to change your password, which also edits the `/etc/passwd` and the `/etc/shadow` files.  Program such as those have the suid bit set so that it will run as `root` even when called by a normal user.

You wouldn't want to change the permissions of your `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files so that you can edit them as a normal user, or so that the `passwd` command will work without the `suid` bit set.

So it would depend on which programs that you are installing and the intent of the program provider.

If the program needs root access, the `make install` should set the `suid` bit.  If it isn't intended to work as root and intended to work by for a normal user, the program or install is broke and should be addressed to the developer so they could fix it.

You might find notes in the `Readme` of the program to fix the bugs, which would be in this case, if `make install` is failing and causing you to have to go in and fix it.

Comment: Perhaps it is a bug in their `Makefile`.  I would need to test this to be certain but I recall compiling and installing the same application (maybe [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/)) on both CentOS and Ubuntu systems (they could not access the internet) and could run the application out of the box on CentOS but not Ubuntu.  This is why it seems like a system configuration/setting.

Comment: The `Makefile` is provided by the program's developer.  It's the `Makefile` that would actually set the `suid bit` and the `userID` so that the program would run by the intended user with the intended permissions.  If the program doesn't do that, and that's the expected behavior, then, as I mentioned in the answer, it's broken and should be brought to the attention of the developer.  By the way, I built and installed the `htop` from the git site you linked.  It works without running it with `sudo`.

Comment: @stvn66 Is the `htop` one of the programs that won't run unless you use `sudo htop`?  Also, to build it I had to install the `libncursesw5-dev` with `apt-get`.  Other than that the one liner install instructions from the `Readme` worked perfect.  If it doesn't work perfect for you, we can investigate why.

Comment: I am not sure which program it was that ran on CentOS but not Ubuntu (it may have been emacs) but your response seems reasonable.  It is good to know this unexpected behavior is not a setting  I can change but oversight of developers (probably not the most important bug they face).

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you run via sudo you are root not your normal user.

Attempts to write config files or setup user versions of libraries will go to /root instead of /home/your_user.

when you run without sudo your programs won't find those files.

You could test this by running your program via strace to see what files it tries to load

```
strace -e open yourprogram
```

Comment: When I install an application using `apt`, `apt-get`, or `dpkg -i` I use `sudo` but all users can run the application.  How do I mimic this behavior when compiling and installing an application from source?  I realize I could add a `chmod` command to the `Makefile` but is there a way to make a change once that will propagate to future installs?